# How to traverse an object array which has elements of the same object

Tags: java, arrays

```
public class Node{
    private String name; 
    private Node parent;
    private Node[] children; // no holes allowed like HW1
    final int maxChildren=10; 
}
```

The Node[] children contains other nodes which also have children nodes. How can I traverse all the "Node" elements in every Node within this  tree.

Comment: probably with a Depth First Traversal (search is your friend)

Comment: Use a for loop and recursion.

Answer (score 0):

> How to traverse an object array which has elements of the same object

It will be a recursive one. To do a depth-first traversing, visit each node, let each node perform a traversing:

```
public void traverse(){

    //do what you need for the current node
    //For e.g, print the name

    for(int i=0; i<children.length; i++)
        children.traverse();
}
```